# HTML embed autoplay="false", but still plays automatically

Tags: html, audio

On the front page of [this website](http://www.foracure.org.au/), there is a sticky post titled "National Radio Advertising Campaign ForACURE" which contains the following HTML:

```
<embed type="audio/x-wav" src="http://www.foracure.org.au/wp-content/uploads/FOR-A-CURE-RADIO-Daniel-45sec.mp3" autoplay="false" height="20" width="200" autostart="false">
```

However, when I load this website in Chrome v31.0.1650.57 m, the audio plays automatically, even though both autoplay and autostart are set to false.

Is there a better cross browser method of embedding this audio?

Comment: Probably not helpful but there a new `<audio>` tag in HTML5.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Chrome doesn't seem to understand `true` and `false`. 
Use `autostart="1"` and `autostart="0"` instead.

---

Source: (Google Groups: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/LkA8FoBoleU)

Comment: Update: Chrome 99.0 no longer work. Edge 99.0 also not working. Firefox doesn't seem to auto play.

Answer (score 11):

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls autoplay>
<source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4"> Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Remove `autoplay`
if you want to disable auto playing video.

Comment: Chrome 88.0.4324.146 seem to use the true/false for autoplay but Edge Version 88.0.705.56 does not.  If autoplay is there, edge will start playing.  By removing autoplay, both work correctly, so at least with these versions, this is the best answer.

Answer (score 2):

Just set using JS as follows:

```
<script>
    var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
    vid.autoplay = false;
    vid.load();
</script>
```

Set `true` to turn on autoplay. Set `false` to turn off autoplay.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_av_prop_autoplay

Answer (score 2):

None of the video settings posted above worked in modern browsers I tested (like Firefox) using the `embed` or `object` elements in HTML5. For `video` or `audio` elements they did stop autoplay. For `embed` and `object` they did not.

I tested this using the `embed` and `object` elements using several different media types as well as HTML attributes (like **autostart** and **autoplay**). These videos always played regardless of any combination of settings in several browsers. Again, this was not an issue using the newer HTML5 `video` or `audio` elements, just when using `embed` and `object`.

It turns out the new browser settings for video "autoplay" have changed. Firefox will now ignore the `autoplay` attributes on these tags and play videos anyway **unless you explicitly set to "block audio and video" autoplay in your browser settings**.

To do this in **Firefox** I have posted the settings below:

1. Open up your Firefox Browser, click the menu button, and select "Options"
2. Select the "Privacy & Security" panel and scroll down to the "Permissions" section
3. Find "Autoplay" and click the "Settings" button. In the dropdown change it to block audio and video. The default is just audio.

Your videos will NOT autoplay now when displaying videos in web pages using `object` or `embed` elements.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the mime type to: `type="audio/mpeg"`, this way chrome will honor the `autostart="false"` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I had assumed that autoplay="false" applied to all other browsers, besides Chrome, so I added

```
autoplay="false" autostart="0"
```

to each video tag.  With six videos on the page it was a tower of bable (didn't work).

The solution is to remove autoplay entirely and just add

```
autostart="0"
```

to each video tag. This worked for Chrome, Firefox, and MS Edge.
Apparently the lack of an autoplay attribute is sufficient for the other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

This will prevent browser from auto playing audio.

**HTML**

```
<audio type="audio/wav" id="audio" autoplay="false" autostart="false"></audio>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#audio').attr("src","path_to_audio.wav");
$('#audio').play();
```

Answer (score 0):

<embed ... autostart="0">

Replace false with 0

Answer (score 0):

I removed "autoplay" and "autostart", it worked

This is my code:

```
<video width="427" height="240" controls >
      <source src="/abc.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I had the same experience. I'm building a website where a lot of auto-generated video works as transition animations etc. I'm having the issue that in mobile Safari (iPhone) videos play in a player, with controls - which totally ruins the experience. I'd love to set controls="false" but ridiculously this has the opposite effect in "normal" browsers (I tested Chrome, Safari).

Feels as if Safari is the new IE...

Answer (score 0):

add attribute `controls` to video tag. It worked on my code

Answer (score -1):

the below codes helped  me with the same  problem.
Let me know if it helped.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<audio controls>

<source src="YOUR AUDIO FILE" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

The problem is your plugin. To solve this is to only enter this address:

`chrome://flags/#enable-NPAPI`

Click activate NPAPI, and finally restart at the bottom of the page.

Comment: The beginning sentence looks somewhat incomplete. E.g. *what* is your plugin?