# How to stop embedded videos on my website from autoplaying

Tags: html, video, autoplay

embed src="clip2.mp4" width="600" height="400" scale="aspect" controller="true"

This is the code I have used to display the video onto my website, but does anybody know how to stop the video from automatically playing once the website has loaded?

Answer (score 9):

you need to add these two attributes to the `<embed>`

```
autoplay="false"
autostart="false"
```

Some browsers wont recognize `true` or `false`. In such situations try,

```
autoplay="0"
autostart="0"
```

Comment: Gah. Beat me to the second portion of your answer. Chrome has been known to not understand `autostart="false"`. It's an old answer, but: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26310273/4204026

Comment: Thank you the autoplay and autostart = false work perfectly :)

Comment: I wouldn't want to unbury some old question, but this doesn't seem to work for me :/

Comment: I agree with 'Saryk'.  As a counter-example (i.e. where this CAN fail to prevent autoplaying), I find that SOME 'src' links fail and yet others don't fail, when using Firefox v6.0.3 or Waterfox v56.2.5.  Thus, I must conclude that this problem is still with us, for some browsers.