# Embed Video into SharePoint WebPart - Do not play video when page opens

Tags: html, flash, sharepoint

I wrote the following html to embed a flash video into a content webpart:

```
<Embed src="RelativeUrlToFlahFile" TYPE="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="700" height="200"></Embed>
```

Works great, however, since I have several videos in the webparts they all start playing at the same time. I would like the videos to not start when the page opens.

I have tried adding

```
<embed...play="false"
<embed..autoplay="false"
```

but none of my options have worked.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add

```
autostart="false"
```

and in the case you used Chrome
"Chrome doesn't seem to understand true and false. Use autostart="1" and autostart="0" instead."

Source: [HTML embed autoplay="false", but still plays automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20286541/html-embed-autoplay-false-but-still-plays-automatically)