# Stop embedded Javascript song from autplaying on Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, audio

I have the following line:

```
<embed src="/sounds/move.wav" autostart="0" width=0 height=0 id="move_sound" enablejavascript=true>
```

Which autoplays the song on Chrome regardless of any parameters I play with (autoplay, etc.).

Anyone know how to stop it from playing?

**EDIT:** Not the same as the above, I'm dealing only with embed tags and not video tags.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML embed autoplay="false", but still plays automatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20286541/html-embed-autoplay-false-but-still-plays-automatically)

Comment: if autostart attribute is present whatever is inside it will be set to true. Just remove the attribute.

Comment: `autostart` is not part of the [HTML5's `<embed>`element's attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/embed#Attributes).

Comment: @jcubic Tried to remove it, no cigar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using an `audio` tag:

```
<audio src="/sounds/move.wav">
  Your browser does not support the <code>audio</code> element.
</audio>
```

This tag will not autoplay the sound.

Answer (score 1):

You could set `src` to empty string

```
var embed = document.getElementById("move_sound");
var audio = embed.src; // save `src`
embed.src = "";
```

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure but maybe you could stop the audio from playing. with a function you call everytime you switch the src?
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_currenttime.asp
Like this?

```
function start(){    
var embed = document.getElementById("move_sound");
    //load the video etc.
    embed.currentTime = 0;
    embed.pause(); 

   }

function playPause() { 
    if (embed.paused) 
        embed.play(); 
    else 
        embed.pause(); 
}
```