# Stop autoplay for HTML video

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a html video where i have image which loads initially. and that image dissapear and play that video.

I want the image should always appear,unill i click on the image. Once i click on the image, video should play.

Please find the jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/pwxcvxe8/173/

We have tried `autoplay = ""` and also removing autoplay from the video tag but no joy.

What change i need to make, if i want to play the video on click of image?

Comment: possible duplicate of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20286541/html-embed-autoplay-false-but-still-plays-automatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing the `autoplay` from the `<video>` tag worked fine to stop it autoplaying.
To make it so the image plays when you click, use the following jQuery:

```
$('#vid').click(function() {
  $('#vid').get(0).play()
});
```

### [Here is an updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pwxcvxe8/175/)

---

Feel free to ask any questions.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `autoplay="false"` or delete the `autoplay`. This worked for me.

Hope this will help.

Comment: ```autostart``` is not listed as a valid attribute for the video tag. Please see valid attributes https://www.w3.org/html/wiki/Elements/video#HTML_Attributes

Comment: @acabra85 Sorry for the confusion. I just mispelled "autoplay". Thanks for the downvote.

Answer (score 1):

try removing `autoplay="false"` or just remove autoplay property

Answer (score 0):

Here is Updated Code, You Can Remove autoplay attribute from video element, so it will never play autoplay, apart from that if you need to stop autoplay through script you can register event on it and use Dom Method "element.pause()"  to stop the video  [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cp199bz2/)

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the MDN Web Docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video "The autoplay attribute has precedence over preload. If autoplay is specified, the browser would obviously need to start downloading the video for playback."

1. As answered above (by Zac Webb) remove the attribute `autoplay`.
2. And if you have the attribute `preload` make sure it is set to none `preload="none"`, since the default for this attribute is `auto`.

This worked for me.