# Chrome object tag autoplay not working

Tags: html, google-chrome, object-tag

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong, but when I put this tag in:

```
<object width="600" class="attachment" v-for="attachmentUrl in message.attachments" :data="attachmentUrl" :key="attachmentUrl" :type="getFileType(attachmentUrl)" autoplay="false">
                    <param name="autoplay" value="false">
                </object>
```

The video gets rendered fine, but still auto plays. I can confirm the rendered html looks like this:

```
<html><head><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"></head><body><video controls="" autoplay="" name="media"><source src="myvideourlgoeshere" type="video/mp4"></video></body></html>
```

I'm using Version 67.0.3396.99 (Official Build) (64-bit) on Mac OS X.

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML embed autoplay="false", but still plays automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20286541/html-embed-autoplay-false-but-still-plays-automatically)

Comment: I can't get that solution to work so either things have changed or this isn't a dupe. Also their example is using an embed tag, this is using an object tag.

Comment: "To disable video autoplay, autoplay="false" will not work; the video will autoplay if the attribute is there in the <video> tag at all.  To remove autoplay the attribute needs to be removed altogether."
[source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#attr-autoplay)