# HTML emble autostart="1" but can't automatically;

Tags: html, css, embed, autostart

I want make the music automatically,but it dosn't work.
`<embed src="music/1.mp3" autostart="1">`
I tried autostart="true"；

Comment: can u add a working demo?

Comment: What web browser / version are you using?  See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20286541/html-embed-autoplay-false-but-still-plays-automatically

Answer (score 1):

After the policy changes, Chrome doesn't allow autoplaying embed audios.

[Discussion about changes in Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes)

What you can do is to autoplay the **muted** video:

```
<video controls autoplay muted>
    <source src="music/1.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
</video>
```

You can find more work arounds here:
[How to make audio autoplay on chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50490304/how-to-make-audio-autoplay-on-chrome)

Answer (score 0):

You don't want quotes around `1` or `true`. Adding quotes makes them strings as opposed to boolean.

I would suggest looking into using html5's `<audio>` element.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio